# Concatenating mulitple lists stored in one object

Tags: python, praw

I am currently using PRAW to extract comments from a reddit page. I want to match certain words from the comment body to values from a csv file. Here is what I am working with so far:

```
submission.comments.replace_more(limit=None)
for comment in submission.comments.list():
    results = (re.findall(r'[A-Z]{3,5}',comment.body))
    print(results)
```

With an output:

```
[]
['HCMC']
[]
[]
['ASRT']
[]
[]
['CBBT', 'TLSS']
['LLEX']
[]
```

I understand that `comment.body` is really just a collection of lists stored within one object. Is there a way that I can concatenate the lists into one single list?

Comment: You are probably looking for how to merge multiple lists. If you have already googled your question, you may have found about **string** *concatenation*. Well, you can also concatenate lists. Just google for how to *merge* or *extend* instead (the last one is exactly a method of python list objects). Maybe include "python" in your search query. In case you don't have access to a search engine, then you can also try `help(list)` in any python console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterables`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(re.findall(r'[A-Z]{3,5}',comment.body)
                             for comment in submission.comments.list()))
['HCMC', 'ASRT', 'CBBT', 'TLSS', 'LLEX']
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just iterate through the `results` and rewrite it's items to the new list like that:

```
concatenated = []
for lst in results:
  for item in lst:
    concatenated.append(item)
```

many other ways in this article: https://www.pythonpool.com/flatten-list-python/